# Can Arkham Horror be played with both The King In Yellow herald, and The King in Yellow ancient one?

Tags: arkham-horror

When playing Arkham Horror, and using The King In Yellow expansion and herald, can The King In Yellow be used as the ancient one as well, or does using it as the herald mean it should not be the ancient one?

If both can be used at together/at the same time, are any special modifications needed to the gameplay?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, there is no specific King in Yellow great old one.

If you're talking about Hastur as the great old one, that's a different story.  Thematically, The King in Yellow is actually Hastur's avatar.  So, in that sense, it might make perfect sense to use both of them in conjunction.  Mechanically, they're just two parts of the game board that don't need special treatment to use together.